# Use alias in Partition part of BigQuery window functions?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The below gives me error "Unrecognized name: country_alias".

```
select         year
               , case when g.country = 'Australia' then 'Australia' else 'Other' end as country_alias
               , count(distinct g.user_id) OVER (PARTITION BY country_alias) as user_count_country
from           people as g 
where          year = 2021
order by       1,2
```

I assume then that it's not possible to leverage a column alias as part of the partition in a windows function? Or have I got the syntax wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can leverage column aliases as part of window. Actually what you could do is this

```sql
select         year,
               count(distinct g.user_id) OVER 
                (PARTITION BY case when g.country = 'Australia' then 'Australia' else 'Other' end) as user_count_country
from           people as g 
where         year = 2021
order by       1,2

-------------------OR You could also do this--------------------

select *, count(distinct g.user_id) OVER (PARTITION BY country_alias) as user_count_country 

from (

        select          year,
                        case when g.country = 'Australia' then 'Australia' else 'Other' end as country_alias
                from           people as g 
        where          year = 2021


) as _table
order by       1,2
```

The reason for using a subquery here is that the order of execution OVER() is same as SELECT. So, when you try to alias a column in SELECT and use with OVER() then its not visible to the OVER() and it complains about that. This is what is happening in your case here.